# Could not able to execute list of openssl command via gitbash using java langauge

Tags: java, openssl, command-prompt, git-bash, self-signed-certificate

I have a requirement where my gitbash should get open and execute openssl commands from java code.
I am able to execute the git version from gitbash via code but could not able to execute the openssl command.its giving me error **"/usr/bin/bash: openssl genrsa -out ABC-RootCA-privatekey.pem 2048: No such file or directory"**
can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code.
I have tried multiple ways to see the output.
please find below code for reference. also I have also shared my output

```
// Java program to illustrate
// open cmd prompt
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.*;

public class GitBash {

public static final String path_bash ="D:/Git/bin/bash.exe"; //     
public static final String path_repository = "cd D:/Git";       
public static final String git_command = "git version";
public static final String command_pipe = path_repository + " && " + git_command;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {       
    System.out.println("Start 1 -->");
    runCommandPIPE(command_pipe);
    System.out.println("End 1 -->");
}

public static void runCommandPIPE(String command) throws IOException {
    try {
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
        processBuilder.command(path_bash, "-c", command);

        // Process and Reader Output
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
          new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
            System.out.println("--> "+line);
        }
        int exitVal = process.waitFor();
        if (exitVal == 0) {
            System.out.println(" --- Command run successfully");
            System.out.println(" --- Output=" + output);
        } else {
            System.out.println(" --- Command run unsuccessfully");
        }
        
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(" --- Interruption in RunCommand: " + e);
        // Restore interrupted state
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    
     ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("D:/Git/bin/bash.exe", "openssl genrsa -out ABC-RootCA-privatekey.pem 2048");

     pb.inheritIO();
        try {
            Process proc = pb.start();
            int exitStatus = proc.waitFor();
            System.out.println(exitStatus);
        }
        catch (IOException | InterruptedException x) {
        }
       
}
  
}
```

**Output** :
Start 1 -->
--> git version 2.39.1.windows.1
--- Command run successfully
--- Output=git version 2.39.1.windows.1

/usr/bin/bash: openssl genrsa -out ABC-RootCA-privatekey.pem 2048: No such file or directory
127
End 1 -->

Comment: Your first command is passing `-c` as a parameter, the second command does not do that.

Comment: You probably need to pass `-c` - that, or `openssl` is not on the PATH.

Comment: How do i execute openssl command from git bash using process builder